# Why c++ compiler does not generate default construction function in some condition but generate it in other conditions

Tags: c++, class, object, copy-constructor

The toy code is like this:

```
class DD {
    public:
        int a{0};
        int b{0};

        DD(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};

void main() {
    DD d1;
    DD d2(d1);

}
```

This will not pass compile check since I defined the construction function of `DD(int a, int b)` with which the compiler will not generate default construction function. However, it seems not affect the generation of the default construction function of `DD(DD& d)`

```
class DD {
    public:
        int a{0};
        int b{0};

        DD(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};

void main() {
    DD d1(1, 2);
    DD d2(d1);
}
```

Why can this work ? It seems that as I defined the `DD(int, int)`, the compiler will not generate other default construction functions, but why can I still construct the object with `DD(DD&)` ?

Comment: Have a look at: https://foonathan.net/images/special-member-functions.png

Comment: Note that in that table (and in general) "default constructor" means "a constructor callable with 0 arguments".

Comment: `DD(DD& d)` is not "default construction function". It's the copy constructor. Actually it's not even that, the copy constructor would be `DD(const DD &);`. The rules for when the default constructor gets deleted and when the copy constructor gets deleted are different. Just because one is deleted doesn't mean the other one is too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- `D(DD&)` **is** a copy constructor. A constructor that takes an argument of type `DD&`, `const DD&`, `volatile DD&`, or `const volatile DD&`, followed by no arguments or additional arguments that all have default values, is a copy constructor. [class.copy.ctor]/1. Yes, it's unusual to do anything other than `const DD&`.